# PyLatex suppress page numbers

Tags: pylatex

I have tried a bunch of things to suppress page numbers and no matter what i do they don't suppress and if they do my logo header disappears. Does anyone have any suggestions.

```
import pylatex as pyl
from pylatex import Document, Section, Subsection, Command,Enumerate,Package,Head, Foot, MiniPage,PageStyle,StandAloneGraphic,Figure,LineBreak,FlushLeft,Command
from pylatex.utils import italic, NoEscape
from pylatex.basic import NewLine
import pylatex.config as cf
import os
from pylatex.base_classes import Environment

cf.active = cf.Version1(indent=False)
doc = pyl.Document()
doc.packages.append(pyl.Package('graphicx'))
doc.packages.append(pyl.Package('fancyhdr'))


doc.preamble.append(pyl.Command('pagestyle', 'fancy'))
doc.preamble.append(pyl.Command('lhead',arguments=pyl.NoEscape(r'\begin{picture}(0,0) \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{Yourlogo.png}} \fancyfoot{} \end{picture}')))



doc.append ("""FULLNAME
CUSTADDRESS
CUSTCITYSTATEZIP

Regarding:  Service Request Number: [REQUESTID]
Affected Address: [PROBFULLADDRESS]

Dear [FULLNAME]

""")
    
doc.append("""Paragraph1""")


with doc.create(Enumerate(enumeration_symbol=r"\alph*)")) as enum:
    enum.add_item("item 1")
    enum.add_item("item 2")
    enum.add_item("item 3")
    enum.add_item(NoEscape("item 4"))

doc.append("paragraph 2")

doc.append("paragraph 3")  

with doc.create(Enumerate(enumeration_symbol=r"\arabic*)")) as enum:
    enum.add_item("item 1")
    enum.add_item("item 2")
    enum.add_item("item 3")
    enum.add_item("item 4")        
    enum.add_item(NoEscape("item 5"))

doc.append("Paragraph 4")
doc.append(NewLine())
doc.append(NewLine())
doc.append("If you have any question")
doc.append(NewLine())
doc.append(NewLine())    
doc.append("Sincerely,")
doc.append(NewLine())
doc.append(NewLine()) 
doc.append("Customer Service")
doc.append(NewLine())     
doc.append("DNP")


doc.generate_pdf('lettertest1', clean_tex=False,compiler='LuaLaTeX')
```

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Comment: `\fancyfoot{}` inside a picture environment won't do much. This should go into the preamble.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ended up cheating.  I wrote the letter in pylatex and did a pdf merge using pypdf2 with letter head as the background.  Worked well.